# how to set up virtual host in nginx?

Tags: nginx, web, fastcgi, php

I am using below configuration settings but it is downloading index source file on execution. But it is showing output of index.html if it is put instead of index.php

Overall it seems it is not reading php file.

```
 server {
 server_name test.com;

 root /var/www/test;

 index index.html index.php;

 # serve static files directly
 location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html)$ {
 access_log off;
 expires max;
}

location / {
    # Check if a file or directory index file exists, else route it to index.php.
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
deny  all;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must setup the PHP-FPM or fastcgi, if not you will get the plain file:

```
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/test/index.php;
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_pass_header Host;
fastcgi_pass_header X-Real-IP;
include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
```

And PHP-FPM should be running in port 9000

Comment: do I need to install something before I set up fastcgi? I have installed nginx and is that enough ?

Comment: You need php-fpm, running as a service. This will execute your php files.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am able to execute php files now. But it is not taking any other url. I mean in Apache we o mod_rewrite, similarly wat do we need to do here? for example `https://test.com/auth/register` is not recognizing

Comment: Then you must change /var/www/test/index.php by something like /var/www/test/$uri

Answer (score 1):

Here's my basic virtualhost file

```
server {
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    root /path/to/root;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$request_uri;
    }
    location ~* \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix://var/run/php5-fpm.sock # if you use sock files
        fastcgi_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000; # if you use port 9000
    }
}
```

You need to comment one of the `fastcgi_pass` lines, according to what your website uses. and of course you need to customize the `try_files` line to match how your php gets the route, if you use `QUERY_STRING` for example you might do something like

```
try_files $uri $uri/ index.php?$request_uri; # mind the extra `?`
```

Also double check the path of the sock file in the `/var/run` directory if you are getting a bad gateway [502] error